# Using lxml, how can I find and collect all the elements in between specific types of tags?

Tags: html-parsing, lxml

I have an html document with internal links (i.e., `<a name="blah"></a>` tags) at the start of certain sections.

I want to visit each internal link, and grab all the text contained in all the elements recursively in between.

For example, in between these 2 links:

```
<A name='G27866101'>
<DIV align="left" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica; color: #000000; background: transparent">
    <B><FONT style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times">About This Section</FONT></B>
</DIV>
</A>

<DIV align="left" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; text-indent: 3%; font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times; color: #000000; background: transparent">
    This section is part of a registration that we filed with the proper authorities ... blah ... for more information.
</DIV>

<A name='G27866102'>
```

I want to retrieve:

```
About This Section

This section is part of a registration that we filed with the proper authorities ... blah ... for more information.
```

And since the elements between links can have nested elements, I want to get all that text as well (i.e., recurse through each child element and get that text).

For example, from this:

```
<A name='G27866102'>
<DIV align="left" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica; color: #000000; background: transparent">
    <B><FONT style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times">Additional Information</FONT></B>
</DIV>
</A>

<DIV align="left" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; text-indent: 3%; font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times; color: #000000; background: transparent">
    As permitted by house rules, this section is ... 
    <DIV><FONT style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times">There's nested text here<FONT></DIV>
    ... blah ... the actual document.
</DIV>
```

I'd like to get:

```
Additional Information

As permitted by house rules, this section is ... There's nested text here ... blah ... the actual document.
```

I know about using `findall('//a')` and checking the `attrib` hash for a 'name' key, but that just gets me the `<a  name="blah"></a>` tag elements.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to define a recursive `get_all_nodes_in_between()` function that would work like this:

```
anchors = html.findall('//a')
for i, anchor in enumerate(anchors):
    if anchor.attrib.has_key('name'):
        all_elements = get_all_nodes_in_between(anchor, anchor[(i+1)]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Are you required to use lxml or can you use BeautifulSoup?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I'm using BeautifulSoup within lxml (http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) right now, but I could use BeautifulSoup alone as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in BeautifulSoup by the checking for the DIV tag and grabbing all data within there:

**Edited code from comments:**

```
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    import re

    html ='''
        <A name='G27866101'>
<DIV align="left" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica; color: #000000; background: transparent">
    <B><FONT style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times">About This Section</FONT></B>
</DIV>
</A>

<DIV align="left" style="margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%; text-indent: 3%; font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times; color: #000000; background: transparent">
    This section is part of a registration that we filed with the proper authorities ... blah ... for more information.
</DIV>

<A name='G27866102'>
    '''
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    for item in soup.findAll('div'):
        print ''.join(item.findAll(text=True))
```

outputs:

```
About This Section


This section is part of a registration that we filed with the proper authorities ... blah ... for more information.
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer the question. I don't want all the text, just the parts in between the anchors. And it's not really about the text: in more general terms, I want to be able to collect, recursively, all the elements in between two given elements.

Comment: That still doesn't work, because I don't know which or how many elements I have between the `<a name=''></a>` tags.  I could, for example, have this:  `<a name='link1'></a><p></p><div></div><p><div></div><div></div></p><a name='link2'></a><div></div><a name='link3'></a>` etc.